# Making 2 requests delete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

Im using ajax to make a delete request, but for some reason, after making the first request to the right route, it makes another request to the current route. I only immplement the submission to the route of /products/id and not to the current route that is /galleries/id

My ajax is :

```
 //Deleting records


   $(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/products/"+id,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: {
                        "id": id,
                        "_method": 'DELETE',
                        "_token": '{{Session::token()}}',
                    },
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        console.log("it Work");
                        $('#delete').hide();
                    }
                });

        console.log("It failed");
        $('#delete').show();
    });
```

delete controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = PhotoGallery::find($id);  
        $product->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'The product was successfull deleted');
        return back();
    }
```

route:

```
Route::delete('products/{id}', 'PhotoGalleryController@destroy');
```

Note: The product im deleting in ajax is a list of products that are inside of a form

```
<form method="POST"  id="myform" action="/galleries/{{$gallery->id}}"  class="" role="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                        {{csrf_field()}}
```

Comment: Can you share your `delete` method from Controller?

Comment: What does the html look like, what is `.deleteProduct`? If it is a submit button on a form, you need to cancel the click event.

Comment: i already added more info above

Comment: did you try event.preventDeafault() before calling ajax ?